# 2009 Crown Victoria-- Problem

Tags: ford, crown-victoria

I'm having trouble with my 2009 Crown Victoria. I was driving down the highway when my Low Tire Pressure Signal came on and then went off.  The light came on  again and then I noticed that I was losing power in my call and the speedometer the rev-meter were jumping up and down. Ultimately the car would no longer move forward and when I put the car in park it makes a screeching noise.  I went out and checked the wheel (rear passenger side) and noticed fluid leaking on the tire and on the brake drum.

What could this be? thanks

Comment: When you said, "*losing power in my call*" ... what does that mean (or is it a mistyped statement)?